# copy armature with rig to another blender file

Tags: rigging

I am unable to copy the armature of my character when i have bone groups/ik added to them, they will completely bug out when copied as can be seen in image below:
[image]
The object itself also loses its pose and goes back into T-pose mode.
Duplicating works but i cant use it because i wanna copy the character between blender files, with a normal armature and bones without any IK and groups it works perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal workflow for this is to have your whole character (models, armature and anything needed for it) in a collection.

Then when you need this character in another .blend file, go to the menu File > Append, open the .blend file containing your character, then go to its Collections folder, and select your character's collection.